# Find a record, but to ignore the listed characters when comparing (for example ?% $ @ & )with the article title in database

Tags: php, mysql, regex, regexp-replace, regexp-like

Salutation!
In the database, the article name is stored with a question mark at the end(Is life after death?). How to  write a regular expression correctly so that the search does not take into account the characters in brackets, i.e. the question mark and others too?

The option below does not work.

```
$article="Is life after death";
$sth = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article REGEXP '/.'?'[?%$@&]./'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sth);

$sth->bindParam(1, $article, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

It is necessary for the code to find the article name in the database using the name from the $article variable, even if the article in the database looks like this: %#Is life? after death?&.

Comment: Please add more details, with some data, what are the source and what should be found with the regular expression

Comment: I fixed my post please look it out.

Comment: Consider using a `FULLTEXT` index for searching by "words".